# Saving a .tar.gpg file

Tags: encryption

Saving a `.tar` file in Emacs works as expected. Saving a `.gpg` file also works as expected.

However, when I save a `.tar.gpg` file, instead of saving an encrypted form of the actual tar file, it instead saves an encrypted form of what the tar file appears in `tar-mode`.

For example, I create a tar archive with the file `abc.org` which has "Hello World!" in it. When I `file` it, I get this:

```
test.tar: tar archive
```

However, if I save the same tar file as a `test.tar.gpg` in Emacs, I get this when decrypted:

```
decrypted.tar: ASCII text
```

I believe this is because EasyPG doesn't understand that what's in the buffer isn't what needs to be saved. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: I'd write to Emacs mailing list. Seems like the developers simply forgot about this.

Comment: FYI https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=37454